# Getting notified when my iPhone is found at a different email address?

Tags: iphone, icloud, find-my-iphone

If my iPhone gets stolen and I try to use Find my iPhone while it's off, I am given the option to be notified by email when my iPhone is found.

I believe this sends an email to my iCloud account.

I see 2 problems with this:

1. Since my iCloud address was automatically set up to receive email on my iPhone, the person who currently has possession of the phone will also be notified when my phone was located. They could then take measures in order to make it harder to find the phone. Ideally they wouldn't get a notification message when my phone is found.
2. My iPhone was the only place that I used to get my iCloud messages. Right now I would need to manually login to iCloud.com and check the email every so often to see if it's been located. I realize that I could use an application such as Apple's Mail app to check this account automatically, but I am not using Mail right now. I'm using Gmail instead, and would prefer to get the message at my Gmail address.

Is there any way to send the email to a different address and/or bypass these 2 issues *after* the phone is stolen?

Answer (score 2):

You can setup your gmail account as default iCloud account.

To do this :

1. Go to settings
2. Mail Contacts, Calenders option
3. Add new Email Account
4. Choose iCloud Account
5. Choose Get a Free Apple ID
6. When it asks for Email provide your Gmail Address
7. It will then pair your email with iCloud account so that you can use it as primary iCloud account
8. Once setup is done go to iCloud in Settings and change the account from iCloud me address to your newly setup Gmail iCloud Account

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This seems like you would need the iPhone to do this. What if I want to do this after the phone is stolen?

Comment: You can setup even on Mac or PC if iCloud is installed on them. But it is too late to do so if you want to change after phone is stolen. Because your phone will be setup with old iCloud account.

Comment: I updated the question to clarify that I'm looking for a solution for after the phone is stolen.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution in my mind would be, rather than change the email address, lock the phone first. Then there won't be any updates.

Answer (score 0):

You can just change all your passwords that way your emails won't be sent to that device because you have changed all the passwords.

Answer (score -2):

You can go to your email's settings and forward all your emails to a different email address.

---

Elaborating on this further, you can set up your existing email to forward your emails to another email address which is **not** synced to your phone.

You can set up the forwarding from any browser & the thief will not have access to the account.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more in detail how this works and how this would solve the asker's problem?